# hive or spark sql delimited list of value:count?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql

There is a sql function called `collect_set()` which takes a column as an argument and returns a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated.

I would like to know if there is a way to get both the set of objects with the count of those objects?

```
example
columnA 
A
A
B
C

collect_set(columnA) => [A:2, B:1, C:1]
```

If there is a straightforward way, please let me know.  So far, I have not found any.  The alternative is to do a group by that column to have unique set of column values and the respective count on separate rows vs as a delimited list in one row/column.

Thanks!

Comment: " So far, I have not found none" may I know the meaning ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no other straight forward way apart from 1 ) collect_set 2) group by as you mentioned

Comment: @RamPrasadG - I am going to correct that sentence :)  I meant to say that I have not found any way to do this.  Thanks for confirming - I wanted to make sure that there was a function that I did not know about.

Comment: yes I even cross checked, collect_set with out duplicates , collect_list is with duplicates (we need to group manually)